# In Java, how do I check if a string begins and ends the same way?

Tags: java

I'm learning Java, and I'm completing some problems tasked to me.

I've come across a specific problem and I feel like the answer is so simple, but I just can't find it.

I need to check if given string ends with the first two characters it begins with. For example, "edited" (begins and ends with "ed")
I've tried using the java endsWith and startsWith, but I keep getting an error

```
 start = text.startsWith(text.substring(0,2));
```

Yeilds

*Error: incompatible types
  required: java.lang.String
  found:    boolean*

Any help would be appreciated.

Thankyou.

Comment: what is the type of start?

Answer (score 6):

You're calling `startsWith` when you don't need to - you know it starts with the first two characters, by definition :)

You could have:

```
String start = text.substring(0, 2);
boolean valid = text.endsWith(start);
```

Or just collapse the two:

```
boolean valid = text.endsWith(text.substring(0, 2));
```

I'm assuming you already know the string is of length 2 or more... if not, you should check that first. (And change the variable `valid` to whatever makes sense in your context.)

Answer (score 0):

This is a dynamic code for what you need to do

let's say we have

```
    String testak = "tesHJKLtes"
    //index you need to check here 2
    int ind = 2;
```

ind is the index you need to check

```
    if ( testak.substring(0,ind).equals(testak.substring(testak.length()
     -ind-1,testak.length()-1))){
        System.out.println("yeeaaahhh");
    }
```

and consider that this you are not limited to 2 anymore you can give ind any number you like 
and it will work

Comment: Obviously it works till ind < testak.length()/2, hope it helps